# Is society better off without religion?

Tags: culture, religion

Edit: after reading some of the answers, if i was to rebuild a society, would it be more effective for a society without the needs for religious daily rituals etc... Also would it be better if it was replaced with moral ethics and critical thinking

Comment: It is important to ask whether it is the religion as a whole, or societies views of said belief system, that prelude the civil unrest we witness today.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. I am sorry but I have to put a close-vote on your question because it is not actually about building a fictional world, but is instead a much larger question about the real life that is perhaps better suited for SE Religion, Philosophy and/or Politics. My own personal opinion is that Freedom of Thought and Right to Life are the two most essential rights a person has, and as such **belief** shall always be guaranteed to be free and and not in any way restricted, monitored or controlled. I do think that religion has no place in the public discourse though.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors it doesn't ask the effects of removing religions from society, it asks the differences between a society without religion.

Comment: @user30785 Yes I know that is what OP asked. My comment stands because such a question is **much** too large and too off-topic for SE Worldbuilding.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelKarnerfors that this is huge question and philosophers, theologians and scientists will go great lengths to argue their case. As such, it is not good question for this site. Especially if you don't have rigid definition of what "religion" even is.

Comment: Your assuption is flawed (at least). Conflicts are not caused by religion. But some groups use religion to distinguish between "us" and "them". It's just a figleaf to hide the fact that the conflicts in question are about money and power. Any other figleaf would do, too, but religion is easy to use since it's hard to define who has the "right" interpretation (among other things).

Comment: @Burki And here is why the discussion is too big to fit into an answer here. Whether religion is the direct **cause** or "only" a **facilitator/enabler of conflict** can be debated for a long time. But undoubtedly some religious authoritative texts do have passages that permit the followers to set aside common human morals and ethics that have been arrived at through consensus and agreement, common morals and ethics that would otherwise have prevented these people from engaging in the conflict. And some religious texts even **enjoins** the reader of the text to engage in conflict.

Comment: @Burki And when it comes to religiously authoritative **persons**, well then we know for certain that some of those do call for conflict and will drag others with them. So I will just cut the Gordian knot here and say that: without religion being an influence on people's decisions (i.e. without **theism**), some of the conflicts we are seeing today would not be possible, or would at least be a lot less intense.

Comment: critical thinking is unless based on some kind of agreed upon moral stander. What ever systme believes of morality you used to base your moral  standers on would be your religion so simply put your above society could not exist.

Comment: Remember that even atheism is a technically a form of religion

Answer (score 6):

**Ha!**

> are caused by religious matters

They are justified by (or blamed on) religious matters, that's a bit different thing.

People are warring/killing/hating each other for a plenty of time now, having following as essentional "excuses":

- You don't deserve you possess. (pursuit of justice)
- I need that, what you possess to survive. (self-preservation)
- You're not like me and my group. (social identity)

Religion comes from third group, which also have a plenty of other examples over the course of history (+ today):

"You're not like me (and I hate you), because of": skin color, religion, gender,sexual orientation, your general lifestyle, your attitude towards *something* (includes politics, football teams, being a convinced criminal/law-abiding-citizen, etc.etc.), and many more other things (even just something as silly as "what part of Great Britain do you come from" or "how much do you earn").

If you paint all the people green, make them straight and give them the equal salary, they will just start grouping by teeth length, eye color and favorite season.

**So no, you won't cure humanity and stop the violence purely by removing religion - people will always find a way to team up and justify their hate towards "aliens".**

P.S.:

I tried to keep this answer as short as I could. There actually a lot more to say about subject. **Intraspecific violence of humans is a pretty complex social thing and just removing one factor won't help much**.

P.P.S.:

A willing to "remove religion" can be reasoned in some other ways (like developing critical thinking or some other stuff), so I've answered about "peaceful" part only (the answer is "NO").

**Other parts of your question ("effeciency/effectiveness without religion") are a raw fuel for holy wars, since any religious person's answer would be "Yes, except mine", or simple "No" (assuming the person is logical), while non-religious answers will vary, since religion is a pretty powerfull tool of both control (for church/govt.) and of staying sane / handling difficult life situations in this senseless cruel world (for a lot of people), which can't be thrown away carelessly.**

Comment: +1 sir, unless of course Winter is your favourite season... !

Comment: Religion is a elite tool to control people IN a world you're filling with senseless cruelty.

Answer (score 0):

## No

Religion was a fundamental building block to human history and forms the framework for politics.

Philosophically speaking, it might be possible to create a civilisation that doesn't rely on religion - Plato's [Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_(Plato)) is a prime example.  However, this isn't likely to happen as religion continues to underpin our lives.

Comment: Some would say under*mine* ... ;-) Anyway, i can't agree. Modern constitutionalised democracy is build *around* religion, not based on it.

Answer (score -3):

I dont think so.

Most of the wars today arent really caused by religion, but rather by greed.

Humans will always question their existence, no matter what, therefore religion would exist whenever a intelligent species forms. The bad thing about religion is, that the leaders of certain religious communities were/are cruel and greedy. They exploit the naivety of the people.

For example: 
There is a church in Brazil where you can only enter if you donate 20 or 30 percent of your annual sallary to the church. While people think they're donating to "god's house", they are actually just giving the money to the rich leaders of that church.

Of course, there were wars caused by religion especially in the middle ages, but the time of that is over.

Comment: In history, it has not been the naivety of the followers, so much the desperation said peoples had to live that drove them to "faith". As an example: Christianity proved popular throughout the Roman Empire as it encouraged virtues such as compassion toward those less fortunate and equality between social-teirs, hence benefiting the homeless/neglected/desperately-in-need majority who were able to find comfort and long-jeopary through the kindness of strangers (which they were then able to pay-on to others etc).

Comment: It was likely always and only greed, but how do you rally the masses without religion or pseudo-religions like communism or nazism? Religion is there to implant fear into the people, and thus gain power over them.

Comment: so why am i getting downvoted?

Comment: Religion is a pretty touchy/speculative subject at the best of times, given more of a philosophical then scientific attachment. Remember, you've answering questions in a community where radical *Whovianism* rules above all else... So yeah, I wouldn't take it personally :)

Comment: @Karl You make generalizations to complex maters. Saying that all religion only form because of greed is like saying that all governments form always and only so the strong(and/or rich) can  force the weak to mend to their will.

Comment: @Karl certainly greed will play a role in any religion but  that  has little to do with religion more to do with the fact that humans are greedy. Weather it is business or government greed plays part in everything we do because greed is a part of us. That one the idea of a Utopia is a myth.